# Minecraft server will not work even with ports open everywhere. Why is that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, hosting

My Minecraft server is crashing instantly due to failing to bind a port when I put my Public IP in tp the server.properties file, yet when I make it blank and default to my PC's IP, nobody else can join.

I have not been able to find info about this anywhere online, as almost all of the solutions consider only people of the same network not being able to join as the context. I'm trying to make a Minecraft server for a discord group. No matter what I do, either everyone excluding me cannot join, or my server crashes. I have opened port 25565 on both TCP and UDP on both my Windows Firewall and my router, and I have even tried disabling my firewall altogether. Nothing is working.

```
[23:01:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on xxx.xxx.xx.xx:25565
[23:01:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[23:01:25] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[23:01:25] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
[23:01:25] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
[23:01:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
```

Please give me some info about this that actually works for other people that are not connected to the same network, and no, I am not accepting Hamachi as a solution.

Image provided by a Discord group member (Private IP used):
[image: Image provided by a Discord group member.]

My image of the server being up on my end:
[image: My image of the server being up on my end.]

Edit: I have also registered this domain using Cloudflare, because I wanted to use the domain for my website. Could that be causing interference?

Edit 2: Direct IP access works, but the domain does not, as I just found out recently. Is it an issue with the domain?

Answer (score 1):

you've got a process holding the port,  find it and kill it, or just reboot.

Comment: netstat -aon | findstr "25565" is not returning any processes. Am I supposed to use a different command?